# How to bind a property of a property of a class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding

I have the following class:

```
public class Car
{
    [DataMember(Name = "versionID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "state")]
    public State State { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}


public class State
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "on")]
    public bool StateOn{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "description ")]
    public int Description { get; set; }

}
```

I have a ObservableCollection which I bind to a Listbox as ItemsSource.

ListboxItemTemplate:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
   <ToggleButton Tag="{Binding Description}" IsChecked="{Binding StateOn}"/>
```

How can I bind the StateOn bool of State to the IsChecked of the ToggleButton in the ItemTemplate?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to refer to them like so ...

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
   <ToggleButton Tag="{Binding State.Description}" IsChecked="{Binding State.StateOn}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do this but you can try setting the DataContext within each control but it's kind of ugly, in my opinion:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}">
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
             <local:Car/>
         </TextBlock.DataContext>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}">
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
            <local:Car/>
        </TextBlock.DataContext>
    </TextBlock>
    <ToggleButton Tag="{Binding Description}" Content="{Binding StateOn}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding StateOn, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ToggleButton.DataContext>
            <local:State/>
        </ToggleButton.DataContext>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

And in your code-behind:

```
public class State : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }

    private bool stateOn { get; set; }
    public bool StateOn
    {
        get 
        {
            return stateOn;
        }

        set
        {
            stateOn = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StateOn"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I removed the attributes for now so it won't be too distracting. I also added text content to the ToggleButton just for troubleshooting purposes. You can change the `Mode`to OneWay if you don't want the StateOn bool to change when the user clicks the toggle button. More about `Mode` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx